# Show that $f$ Satisfies the Lipschitz Condition

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have a question here that I do not know how to solve.

If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and there exists a constant $M$ such that for every $a \leq x < b$, there is a decreasing sequence $a_x (n )$ which converges to $x$ such that $\dfrac{f(a_x(n))-f(x)}{a_x(n)-x}$ converge to a point in $[-M,M]$.

Show that $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition.

The problem is that I cannot find ways to transform the given 'sequence' property to the 'property on the line'. Uniformly continuous can be used, but it seems to weak compared with conditions like Lipschitz which requires you to say sth. about $\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. So I also wonder if the problem misses some conditions.

Can anyone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ were differentiable then we could simply use the mean value theorem: For $a \le x < y \le b$ there is a $c \in (x,y)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = f'(c) = \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{f(a_c(n))-f(c)}{a_c(n)-c} \in [-M, M]
$$
and we are done.

But $f$ is only assumed to be continuous. The desired conclusion can still be proven by *mimicking* the proof of the mean value theorem (and Rolle's theorem, on which it is based).

Let $a \le x < y \le b$. We define the function $g: [x, y] \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 g(t) = f(t) - \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} (t-x) \,.
$$
Note that $g(x) = g(y)$, so that $g$ assumes its minimum at some point $c \in [x, y)$. It follows that for all $t \in (c, y)$
$$
 0 \le g(t) -g(c) = f(t) - f(c) - \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}(t-c) \\
\implies \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \le \frac{f(t)-f(c)}{t-c}
$$
and by setting $t = a_c(n)$ we conclude that
$$
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \le \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{f(a_c(n))-f(c)}{a_c(n)-c} \le M \,.
$$
Similarly, by considering the point where $g$ attains its maximum, we get that
$$
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \ge -M
$$
and that finishes the proof.

Comment: If $g$ is not constant on $ [x,y]$ then it may be that its maximum or minimum  on $[x,y]$ might be uniquely achieved at $c=x=a$ or at $c=y=b. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: You are right, thanks! But we can assume that the extremum is attained at $c \in [x, y)$ and the rest should remain valid.

Comment: Actually that simplifies the argument, because the case “$g$ is constant” doesn’t need to be considered separately.

Comment: There is a continuous $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ such that  whenever $x\in [0,1]$ and $U$ is a nbhd of $x$ (in the space $ [0,1]$) then  $(i)... |\{y\in U:f(y)=f(x)\}|=2^{\aleph_0},$ and $(ii)... \sup \{|f(y)-f(x)|/|y-x|:x\ne y\in U\}=\infty$... I have been wondering whether, whenever $0< x<y<1,$ that $\{z\in (x,y):f(z)=f(y)\}$ is infinite. This Q & A shows the answer is "No" because then $f $ would be Lipschitz, contrary to $(ii).$

Comment: @MartinR could you look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474966/lipschitz-condition-and-optimization)