# Lipschitz Condition and Optimization

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lipschitz-functions

I am reading paper on [optimization](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/gonzalez16a.pdf). I am trying to understand the following statement:

[image]
[image]

I would like to ask how the Ball doesnot contain the minimum of f? I would appreciate if this could be graphically shown something like following taken from Bayesian Optimization and Data Science
[image]

Comment: I cannot find that exact paragraph in http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/gonzalez16a.pdf.

Comment: @MartinR It should be in section 2.1. The one mentioned in this post is from the same author but it has less details.

Comment: @MartinR it here in [page 795](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/gonzalez16b.pdf)

Comment: So the statement is in general terms that assuming the function is L-Lipschitz, so for it to have a constant L, the maxima (or minima) must not be in the Ball. My question is why?

Comment: The statement looks wrong to me. Take $f(x) = \Vert x \Vert$ as an example. $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz, and has a minimum at $x^* = 0$. Any ball $B_{r_j}(x_j) = \{ x : \Vert x_j - x \Vert \le \Vert x_j \Vert \}$ contains the point $x^* = 0$.

Comment: @MartinR I see. Does the same logic works on the maximum?